# Store JSON output to array

Tags: arrays, json, windows, powershell

I'm trying to store the output fields to an array for future reference in my script.

```
$rfcrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $rfcuri -Method Get -Headers $headers
$rfc = $rfcrequest.Content |
       ConvertFrom-Json |
       Select-Object -ExpandProperty Result |
       Select-Object -First 1
```

Echoing `$rfc` returns the following:

```
number       sys_created_on     
------       --------------      
CHGOP0007816 2017-07-20 10:20:36
```

My goal is to store the output to an array. What's the best way to achieve this please?

Comment: *"My goal is to store the output to an array."* The individual words make sense, the overall statement however... Is this a question about how to create arrays in Powershell?

Comment: Im asking for help in storing the result in an array.

Comment: What is the array supposed to look like? Do you just want the values (`@('CHGOP0007816', '2017-07-20 10:20:36')`)? Or should the property names be included as well (`@('number', 'CHGOP0007816', 'sys_created_on', '2017-07-20 10:20:36')`)? Perhaps you'd prefer a hashtable over an array (`@{'number' = 'CHGOP0007816'; 'sys_created_on' = '2017-07-20 10:20:36'}`)?

Comment: Never mind guys, figured a way how to retrieve values from the hashtable itself without creating an array by `$rfc.number`. So simple. Just got started with powershell.

Comment: @joebegborg07 I'd suggest writing an answer for anyone who comes across this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I've solved this by extracting the "number" column:

```
$rfc.number
```

In my case this worked because I only had one value in each column.